# generate pandas dataframe from txt file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large txt file with the following format:

```
0
1
2
3
4
La situacion es preocupante
5
6
Radio es parte de la vida
7
Dejare de querer muy pronto
```

I need to generate a pandas dataframe similar to:

```
  Texto
0 NaN
1 NaN
2 NaN
3 NaN
4 La situacion es preocupante
5 NaN
6 Radio es parte de la vida
7 Dejare de querer muy pronto
```

with the following code I get an incorrect output:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("nohup.out",sep="\\n")

    0
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   La situacion es preocupante
5   5
6   6
7   Radio es parte de la vida
8   7
9   Dejare de querer muy pronto
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: It looks correct to me, are there actually columns in the original file?

Comment: hello, it is not correct because "Radio" should be in position 6 and "Dejare" in position 7 but is in position 7 and 9 respectively.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to delete the preceding row if there is a string in one of the columns? 

there are 11 rows in your original data so it makes sense that it would result in a dataframe of length 11.

Comment: the index of each phrase should be the previous number, for example **4
La situacion es preocupante** in dataframe 4 is the index **6
Radio es parte de la vida** Index in dataframe is 6, In other words the numbers in the original data should be the index in the dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) like so:

```
df['0'].replace(to_replace=r'^\d*$', value=np.nan, regex=True)
0                            NaN
1                            NaN
2                            NaN
3                            NaN
4    La situacion es preocupante
5                            NaN
6                            NaN
7      Radio es parte de la vida
8                            NaN
9    Dejare de querer muy pronto
```

Though you may need to tidy up your input file to get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the CSV which does not have a header. In this case, **you can specify the column name while importing the dataframe**.

Also, I guess you need to replace the numeric values to null.
Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("C:/Test/list.txt", names=['Texto']) # read csv with header 'Texto', you don't need to specify separator
print (data)

Out[74]: 
                          Texto
0                             0
1                             1
2                             2
3                             3
4                             4
5   La situacion es preocupante
6                             5
7                             6
8     Radio es parte de la vida
9                             7
10  Dejare de querer muy pronto
```

This is the default result. Now, **to replace the digits with NaN**, try:

```
data['Texto'] = data['Texto'].str.replace('\d+', 'NaN')
print (data)

Out[76]: 
                          Texto
0                           NaN
1                           NaN
2                           NaN
3                           NaN
4                           NaN
5   La situacion es preocupante
6                           NaN
7                           NaN
8     Radio es parte de la vida
9                           NaN
10  Dejare de querer muy pronto
```

**Edit**: As hinted by @jezrael, changed '\d' to \d+' to include multiple digits in the below code:

```
data['Texto'] = data['Texto'].str.replace('\d+', 'NaN')
```

Comment: @jezrael, Not sure if we need np.nan in this case. I guess having a 'NaN' string will automatically be treated as null while reading.